# Shorten long switch case

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, switch-statement

So let me start by saying I am new to C#. I have a switch statement that currently has 10 different cases, however, I need to use it 3 different times (same 10 cases, different results per case), and each case there is only a slight change.

I feel like I'm just repeating code, is there a way to shorten it?

```
//Set the growth time of the crop based on what cropType.
        switch (cropType) {
            case 1:
                //Potatoes
                growth = 60;
                break;
            case 2:
                //Strawberries
                growth = 80;
                break;
            case 3:
                //Cabbages
                growth = 90;
                break;
            case 4:
                //Carrots
                growth = 40;
                break;
            case 5:
                //Melon
                growth = 120;
                break;
            case 6:
                //Pumpkin
                growth = 130;
                break;
            case 7:
                //Eggplant
                growth = 50;
                break;
            case 8:
                //Mushroom
                growth = 70;
                break;
            case 9:
                //Wheat
                growth = 40;
                break;
            case 10:
                //Truffle
                growth = 150;
                break;
        }
```

That is my code for 1 section. In the 2nd section, I assign an image depending on the case, this has to be done separately as it relies on the growth and changes, whereas growth does not. I don't actually use it on the other swithces though. This is another one I have further down:

```
switch (cropType) {
            case 1:
                //Potatoes
                Debug.Log("Potatoes Harvested!");
                Global.potato += 2;
                break;
            case 2:
                //Strawberries
                Debug.Log("Strawberries Harvested!");
                Global.strawberry += 4;
                break;
            case 3:
                //Cabbages
                Debug.Log("Cabbages Harvested!");
                Global.cabbage += 1;
                break;
            case 4:
                //Carrots
                Debug.Log("Carrots Harvested!");
                Global.carrot += 3;
                break;
            case 5:
                //Melon
                Debug.Log("Melons Harvested!");
                Global.melon += 1;
                break;
            case 6:
                //Pumpkin
                Debug.Log("Pumpkins Harvested!");
                Global.pumpkin += 1;
                break;
            case 7:
                //Eggplant
                Debug.Log("Eggplant Harvested!");
                Global.eggplant += 2;
                break;
            case 8:
                //Mushroom
                Debug.Log("Mushrooms Harvested!");
                Global.mushroom += 4;
                break;
            case 9:
                //Wheat
                Debug.Log("Wheat Harvested!");
                Global.wheat += 6;
                break;
            case 10:
                //Truffle
                Debug.Log("Truffles Harvested!");
                Global.truffle += 1;
                break;
        }
```

Basically it is a script that needs to do different things based on what cropType is in it.

Comment: How about first using a meaningful `enum CropType { Potatoes = 1, Strawberries = 2, Cabbages = 3, ... }` instead of just numbers? And then put the growth information into a `Dictionary<CropType, int> { { CropType.Potatoes, 60 }, { CropType.Strawberries, 80 }, ... }` and then use it like `var growth = growthDictionary[cropType];`.

Comment: If you had a polymorphic `Crop` type, you wouldn't need to do any of this. You could define a base `Crop` class with a `Growth` property, then derive types like `Mushroom` and `Eggplant` from it, with an overridden implementation of `Growth` that provides the appropriate value. It would mean you could also do away with having to map numbers to crops.

Comment: @spender - Yes, now with the second example it looks like OP might want a `class Crop { public CropType Type { get; set; } public string Name { get; set; }, public int Growth { get; set; } public int ItemsPerHarvest { get; set; } [...] }`

Comment: This sounds like an [xy problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) after your second update. I think you should post more details about what you're really trying to achieve here. It sounded initially like you wanted to simplify a `switch`, but now it sounds like you have class design problems.

Comment: @spender yes I think a class would definitely work here, as I access the crops a lot from other classes not just this one. I might not do it just because I have limited time as this is an assignment (our assignment was 'make something'), but if I do get time its #1 on my list :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this would be too much, but you can use enums and classes/structs plus a dictionary (as ggorlen suggested)

Why enums? to avoid using hardcoded numbers; less error-prone and will improve readability;

```
private enum CropType
{
    Undefined = 0,
    Cabbages,
    Carrots,
    Eggplant,
    Melon,
    Mushroom,
    Potatoes,
    Pumpkin,
    Strawberries,
    Truffle,
    Wheat
}

private struct Crop
{
    public CropType Type { get; private set; }
    public float GrowthFactor { get; private set; }
    public float HarvestFactor { get; private set; }

    public Crop(CropType type, float growthFactor, float harvestFactor) 
    {
        this.Type = type;
        this.GrowthFactor = growthFactor;
        this.HarvestFactor = harvestFactor;
    }
}
```

```
private Dictionary<CropType, Crop> crops;
private Dictionary<CropType, Crop> Crops 
{
    get 
    {
        if (crops == null) 
        {
            crops = new Dictionary<CropType, Crop>() 
            {
                { CropType.Cabbages, new Crop(CropType.Cabbages, 90, 1) },
                { CropType.Carrots, new Crop(CropType.Carrots, 80, 5) }
                // here you can add the rest of your products...
            };
        }
        return crops;
    }
}

public Crop GetCrop(CropType crop) 
{
    if (!Crops.ContainsKey(type)) 
    {
        Debug.LogWarningFormat("GetCrop; CropType [{0}] not present in dictionary ", type);
        return null;
    }

    return Crops[type];
}
```

Here is where (finally) you will retrieve the values that you want.

```
public float GetGrowthFactor(CropType type) 
{
    var crop = GetCrop(type);
    return crop == null ? default(float) : crop.GrowthFactor;
}

public float GetHarvestFactor(CropType type) 
{
    var crop = GetCrop(type);
    return crop == null ? default(float) : crop.HarvestFactor;
}
```

So you will ask for values in this way;

```
private void Example()
{
    var carrotsGrowth = GetGrowthFactor(CropType.Carrots);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In terms of simplifying a `switch` statement, I think a `Dictionary` (if keys were not sequential integers), enumeration, or a `List` (for something like `1-10` as is the case here) is appropriate, creating a mapped relationship between numbers:

```
int[] growth = {0, 60, 80, 90, 40, 120, 130, 50, 70, 40, 150};
int cropType = 5; // for example
Console.WriteLine(growth[cropType]); // 120
```

Here's a dictionary example, which I think is more comprehensible for humans:

```
Dictionary<string, int> growth = new Dictionary<string, int>()
{
    {"Potatoes", 60}, 
    {"Strawberries", 80}, 
    {"Cabbages", 90}, 
    {"Carrots", 40}, 
    {"Melon", 120}, 
    {"Pumpkin", 130}, 
    {"Eggplant", 50}, 
    {"Mushroom", 70}, 
    {"Wheat", 70}, 
    {"Truffle", 150} 
};

Console.WriteLine(growth["Melon"]);
```

However, having seen your second `switch` statement, it appears your unwieldy `switch`es are symptoms of a larger design problem. You may consider adding a `Crop` class that has member fields for all of the properties you're manipulating, such as `type` and `growth` (and any other properties or functions that describe `Crop`-ness).

In terms of  `Global`, you may consider a second class that aggregates `Crop`s, such as a `Harvest` class with a dictionary that keeps tracks of how much of each crop have been harvested.

Long story short, these design questions can get quite fuzzy and opinion-based, but hopefully this offers some ideas for moving forward.

Comment: I can link the numbers to the words fine, but I don't actually use the growth number in my other cases.

Comment: I think classes are "more comprehensible for humans", and creating elaborate mapping systems for something that can be easily represented using the class system is misguided.

Comment: @spender I'm all for classes, but bringing in a class system just to replace a `switch` seems like severe overkill. It may ultimately be appropriate, but I think there'd need to be much more context for that to be worth the overhead. **Edit:** OP has added a second switch suggesting they have a design problem, so you may have a point here now that they want getters and setters. I can update if OP clarifies this.